# How can I run ASP.NET MVC3 in Apache?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, apache, mono, apache2

I have an Ubuntu 12.10 server installed running Mono 2.10.8. I also have Apache2 running and was able to run ASP.NET with mod_mono version 4. I am now trying to run an ASP.NET MVC3 web app, but I get the error message

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helper, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToke=...' or one of it's dependencies. The System cannot find the file specified.

I know it is running under ASP.NET 4.0 because the Yellow Screen of Death says ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1

I have bin deployed that assembly as well as the other ones needed.

The weird part is that running the command

> sudo xsp4

in the websites directory makes the app work as expected.

How can I troubleshoot what is going on here.

Comment: try mono 3.x and xsp 3.0

Comment: Not an option at this moment.

Comment: It seems, that published application is layed under the folder, where root privileges are needed.